# Need some help to copy and paste

Tags: 14.04

is there any way to copy some number of line from vi editor in Ubuntu terminal and paste it into out side of terminal in any text file?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard) explain what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the text while pressing the left mouse button, right click and select "Copy". Then you can paste anywhere.

When you select with mouse, text is automatically copied to the terminal clipboard. When you right click and select "Copy", it's copied to the X clipboard. (Yes, there are 2 clipboards).

Comment: i am having 1000 lines of text file from that i want to copy some 500 lines in vi editor and i want to paste externally not in vi just in a text file . but i am unable select more than 39 lines from command screen. do you have any solution for this

Comment: You can use `cat <filename>` to output all the content to the command line, then terminal will automatically scroll while you're selecting content. Just remember to increase the scroll limit for your terminal: `Edit` > `Profile Preferences` > `Scrolling` tab, then mark `Unlimited`.

Answer (score 0):

Editors generally edit one whole file at a time...

- You could copy/cut the line you want, create a new file, then paste the line there & save?
- Or you could make a copy of the file, then delete every line except the one you want to save?
- Or you could remember a unique bit of the line, then from a terminal run `grep "unique bit" filename > newfile`